# jquery how to pass parameter to callback function into pipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have the simple example below :

```
function firstFunction(){
  var d = jQuery.Deferred();
  // some very time consuming asynchronous code...
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1');
    d.resolve();
  }, 1000);
  return d.promise();
}
function secondFunction(param){
  console.log('parm = '+param);
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('2');
    d.resolve();
  }, 10);
  return d.promise();
}

firstFunction().pipe(secondFunction('OK'));
```

Resulat :
param = OK 
2 
1 
I lose the sync between functions. 
How t can pass parameter to secondFunction into pipe with sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to do small change:

> Your code will execute `secondFunction` immediately and pass the return value from executing it as the argument to `firstFunction` which is unlikely what you want.

Read the full answer: [Javascript callback function with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003828/javascript-callback-function-with-parameters#13004118)

```js
console.log = function(message) {
  $('body').append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

function firstFunction(){
  var d = jQuery.Deferred();
  // some very time consuming asynchronous code...
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1');
    d.resolve();
  }, 1000);
  return d.promise();
}
function secondFunction(param){
  console.log('parm = '+param);
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('2');
    d.resolve();
  }, 10);
  return d.promise();
}

firstFunction().then(function() {
  secondFunction('OK')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the promise from the callback

Comment: That every asynchronous function should return a promise to be useful. In your case, the `then` callback is missing the `return`, so you can't chain anything onto it.

Comment: Oh wait, you're still using `pipe`?! Replace it with `then` immediately, it's been deprecated for years now!

Comment: @Bergi I just followed by the question :) But I was updated my answer.. Thanks.. About your comment, I don't understand. Do you mean that I should add `return ??` after the line `secondFunction('OK')`? If so, what I need to return?

Comment: @collo21 My pleasure ;) Good luck.

Comment: @MoshFeu: No, *before* `secondFunction('OK')` - you should return the promise you're creating there