# I can't seem to get my arguments to pass into a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

I've created a working recursive for loop, but it only works if my callback has no arguments. I've tried `callback(arguments)` and `callback(...arguments)`.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```html
function loopFunc (numOfSteps, callback) {
    let i = 0;

    if (i >= numOfSteps) {
        let i = 0
        return
    } 
    callback()
    loopFunc(numOfSteps - 1, callback)`enter code here`
}
```

It works if the callback takes no arguments:

```html
function noArgsHello() {
    console.log('hello')
}

const thisWorks = loopFunc(3, noArgsHello);
thisWorks()
```

It doesn't work if the callback takes an argument:

```html
function sayHello (input) {
    console.log(input)
}

const thisDoesntWork = loopFunc(3, sayHello('hello');
thisDoesntWork()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript callback function with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003828/javascript-callback-function-with-parameters)

Comment: `callback` should be a `function` object, not `function` execution result (if the result is not a function object). `const thisDoesntWork = loopFunc(3, function(){sayHello('hello');});
thisDoesntWork();`should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way:

`const thisDoesntWork = loopFunc(3, sayHello('hello');`

You are not passing a callback anymore, but you are executing the `sayHello` function and passing the returned value of that function to the `loopFunc`.

What you can do in these cases, is to use the [bind method of functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for passing the function with arguments:

`const thisDoesntWork = loopFunc(3, sayHello.bind(sayHello, 'hello'));`

Or you can pass directly a function which executes your `sayHello` so that the argument is still a function and it will be used as callback inside your `loopFunc`:

`const thisDoesntWork = loopFunc(3, () => sayHello('hello'));`

Comment: Thank you! This is an important distinction. I failed to realize that sayHello('hello') is just a returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You almost there! It depends what is your goal here, you can use either option:

```
function loopFunc (numOfSteps, callback) {
let i = 0;

  if (i >= numOfSteps) {
      let i = 0
      return
  }

 callback(numOfSteps)
 loopFunc(numOfSteps - 1, callback);
}

function printExtraStuff(greeting) {
  return (val) => { console.log('greeting ', val)}
}

function printSteps(num) {
    console.log(num);
}

var test1 = function() { loopFunc(3, printExtraStuff('hi there') )};
test1()

var test2 = function() { loopFunc(3, printSteps )};
test2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anonymous function if you want to pass parameters in an argument -based function (`callback` is an argument). Your code should instead be like this:

```js
function sayHello(input) {
  console.log(input)
}

const works = () => sayHello('hello'); 
works();
```